# How to pull First Date of a Fiscal Week calendar

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have a Fiscal Calendar table in SQL Server 2012 Express.  I would like to be able to pull the first date of each week and display them in a row starting from next week.  Meaning, I want the first row to display 9/2/2013, then 9/9/2013, 9/16/2013, etc.  Here is how I have the table constructed along with some data.

```
[dbo].[FiscalCalendar](
    [FiscalDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FiscalWeekNum] [smallint] NULL,
    [FiscalMonthNum] [smallint] NULL,
    [FiscalMonthName] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [FiscalYear] [smallint] NULL

FiscalDate          FiscalWeekNum   FiscalMonthNum  FiscalMonthName FiscalYear
2013-09-02 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-03 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-04 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-05 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-06 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-07 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-08 00:00:00.000 36          9           September   2013
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
2013-09-11 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
2013-09-12 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
2013-09-13 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
2013-09-14 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
2013-09-15 00:00:00.000 37          9           September   2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT <cols>, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY FiscalWeekNum ORDER BY FiscalDate)
  FROM dbo.FiscalCalendar
  WHERE FiscalDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, FiscalDate) = 2
)
SELECT <cols> FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: That works great, but I need to go into the next year as well and it stops at 52 weeks it seems...

Comment: Ok, now I need to know how to pull each date in order for a row header.  I'm looking to get Week of: 9/2/2013, Week of: 9/9/2013, etc.

Comment: Do you mean **column** header? Perhaps you should start a new question.